# Calling a standard library from imported module

Tags: python

Is it a good idea to use a standard library function from an imported module? For example, I write a xyz.py module and within xyz.py, I've this statetment `import json`

I have another script where I `import xyz`. In this script I need to make use of json functions. I can for sure `import json` in my script but json lib was already imported when I import xyz. So can I use xyz.json() or is it a bad practice?

Comment: I wouldn't use `xyz.json` i would `import json` in that other script, don't depend on `xyz` doing extra work for you

Comment: Yes, that would be confusing. Just `import json`, if it has already been imported, Python doesn't reload it, it simply attaches it to the current namespace

Answer (score 2):

You should use `import json` again to explicitly declare the dependency. 
Python will optimize the way it loads the modules so you don't have to be concerned with inefficiency.

If you later don't need xyz.py anymore and you drop that import, then you still want `import json` to be there without having to re-analyze your dependencies.